# Search over whole array in ruby over 2 Joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, join

Hello is there a way of searching the whole array in ruby if I have the following situation.

Models:
Deal,
Book,
Category

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
has_and_belongs_to_many :deals

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :books

end
```

So if i do the following in the console:

```
Deals.first.books
```

-> I get all the books which belong to the first Deal.

But  now I want to get all the Books from the first deal which have for example 2 special categories. But something like this doesnt work:

```
Deal.first.books.all.categories.where(:name=>"Bestseller")
```

If I do the following:

```
Deal.first.books.first.categories.where(:name=>"Bestseller")
```

it works but gives me obviously only if the first book have this category. How can I get all books from the first deal which have the Bestseller category or even 2 categories.

Every hint or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @bjhaid, think you need `where(categories: { name: "Bestseller" })`

Comment: this `Deal.includes(:books).includes(:categories).where(categories: { name: "Bestseller" }).first.books`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single

```
Deal.includes(books: :categories).where(categories: {name: "Bestseller"}).books
```

For single / multiple

```
Deal.includes(books: :categories).where(categories: 
    {name: ["Bestseller","Hot Stuff"]}).books
```

Comment: This worked for me: So adding a "first" before .books made the job perfect. Deal.includes(books: :categories).where(categories: {name: "Bestseller"}).first.books

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read well enough!  Glad you got it working!